# Confirm and agree to negative questions

Tags: questions, negation

on the internet I read the following explanation:
"we aren't using "no" to agree, we are using "no" to CONFIRM the negative statement."

Does that mean you confirm a negative question with no and agree with yes? That somehow seems strange to me?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: It means that on that particular statement you do. It is not an expression of a grammatical rule. It's a clarification so this vote doesn't get counted wrong.

Comment: I just searched online (via a Google search) for the wording "we aren't using 'no' to agree, we are using 'no' to CONFIRM the negative statement"—and the only matches returned are to this question on English Language & Usage. I had hoped to find the original example that your question quotes, but instead I'm left to wonder whether the quotation itself is inexact. Can you double-check your original source?

Comment: One would have to see more of the context to understand what was meant and determine if it made sense.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what the OP is asking about (as I understand it) would be:

Alice: "Didn't you hear about the party?"

Bob: "No, I didn't hear about it."

Here, Alice's question is in the negative.  Bob says "no", but this actually confirms that he didn't hear about the party.  If he wanted to say that, contrary to what Alice suggests, he had heard about the party, he would say "Yes, I did."

I agree, this is kind of weird.

More examples at http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv330.shtml

Comment: But I could also reply with, “No, I heard about it- I just didn’t want to go.”

Comment: Earlier tonight, I caught myself doing the opposite of what OP asked about/what the BBC website says.  Someone asked me "don't you like it?" and I said "No, I like it."  So I think the behaviour asked about by the OP and described on the BBC website is not universal.